# Json object won't download every time

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api

I have made a windows desktop app that uses a Twebbrowser1 to log the users into their Facebook account, i have completed the requirements to log in and get permissions from users to allow our app to access their albums and pictures etc.

Everything works on the page when the twebbrowser1 lands on our registered apps landing page. So Far so good I get all the info required like the users access key, name, icon etc. I then use this info to create a string to get the json object from Facebook using a function called downloadfile with the following paths.

```
DownloadFile('https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=picture,
    albums.limit(240).fields(photos.limit(2400).fields(source,picture),name,count)
    &access_token=' + '******scraped users access token*********','c:\pictures\me')
```

This gave me the json object `me` faithfully stored in the `c:\pictures` which i then decode using string functions to extract the users picture locations on Facebook. So I can display them to user in my desktop app.

This has worked great for over a month but recently the Function `Downloadfile` has stopped working faithfully.

Comment: Please test your users access token at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug, check the "Expires" field, and check "Scopes:" field have "user_photos" permission. Also, try open https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=%2Fme%3Ffields%3Dpicture%2Calbums.limit(240).fields(photos.limit(2400).fields(source%2Cpicture)%2Cname%2Ccount) and replace the "Access Token:" field with your user access token.

Comment: Also it would be nice if you could tell us if you are getting any errors, or post part of your problematic code. People can't help you without these information.

Comment: Thanks Anvesh I have reprogrammed the server to get the users files instead of my app which is working great.At the time facebook were working heavily on thier security, now its settled down i am just having to reprogram my app to compensate.